# Trying to use groupby() in python to create a summarized dataframe with certain groups filtered out

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I think I might be over complicating this but essentially what I am trying to do is take the data-frame below and group by the unique values in the "MATNR_BATCH" column and create another data frame with the columns: "STORAGE_BIN",  "FULL_IND" & "PRCNT_UTIL", "MAX_NO_SU_IN_SB", "NO_SU_IN_SB":

From something like this:

[image: Part of the original data frame]

To something like this:

[image: Subset/Grouped data frame]

From here what I would like to do is only filter on the "groups" (MATNR_BATCH) that have a mix of "FULL" and "NF" values in the "FULL_IND" column. So basically, I would like to create a data-frame that only has the unique "MATNR_BATCH" (groups) that have a combination of both "FULL" and "NF" in them.

Can anyone please help me out with this? I have been struggling to come up with a way to do this in python. Is groupby the right function to use or should I try and take a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

As a first pass do

```
df1 = df[(df.FULL_IND=='FULL')| (df.FULL_IND=='NF')]
```

And then carry on. I can't quite figure out what you want to do with the other columns.

Comment: thank you for sharing. How do I properly groupby the column of interest first to give me a summarized dataframe? I tried using groupby, but it doesn't reproduce a dataframe for me unless I perform an operation on it.

Comment: @IfadNoor that is why you want to explain what you want to do to each column.